# How do you generate a public key using a Ledger Nano S with NEAR Shell?

Tags: nearprotocol

The Wallet UI has options for "Connect Ledger" under "Full Access Keys" but how do you do it from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

The NEAR CLI README (See [1](https://github.com/near/near-shell)) contains the command to generate a key. It's always good to start with the latest version, so from the CLI run:

```
npm update -g near-cli
```

...and then you can run the key gen command and pass it a bogus account ID:

```
near generate-key foobar --useLedgerKey
```

It will prompt you to connect your Ledger and open the NEAR app (See [2](https://github.com/near/near-ledger-app)), then output something like:

```
Generated key pair with ed25519: your-generated-key-here public key
```

Edit: formatting